# Powershell Multiple StartsWith clauses

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm stripping lines out of a file that start with '713', '714', etc. I'm currently doing so like this:

```
$stripped = $stripped | where{-Not $_.StartsWith('713')}
$stripped = $stripped | where{-Not $_.StartsWith('714')}
$stripped = $stripped | where{-Not $_.StartsWith('715')}
$stripped = $stripped | where{-Not $_.StartsWith('716')}
$stripped = $stripped | where{-Not $_.StartsWith('717')}
```

This feels super-sloppy. How can I improve this code?

Comment: Consider putting questions like this on code review stack exchange.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter CodeReview wants complete code from what I gather. I don't know how the respond to snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few things would work here. First we could use array notation with your number sequence and the operator `-notin`. We need to extract the first charaters for a simple comparison in order for this to work.

```
$stripped = $stripped | Where{$_.substring(0,3) -notin (713..717)}
```

So if the first 3 characters are in the number range then they are skipped.

For other solutions we could use regex since there is a noticeable pattern in your numbers. You could use a pattern to not match numbers from 713 - 717 that are at the beginning of the string.

```
$stripped = $stripped | where{$_ -notmatch "^71[3-7]"}
```

Let says there was not a pattern and you just didn't want any of a series of strings at the beginning.

```
$dontMatchMe = "^(" + ("Test","Bagel","123" -join "|") + ")"
$stripped = $stripped | where{$_ -notmatch $dontMatchMe}
```

The caret `^` is a regex anchor for the beginning of the string. So we build an array of string that we don't want and join them with a pipe character and enclose it in brackets. It would look like this in my example:

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> $dontMatchMe
^(Test|Bagel|123)
```

You need to be careful with your string in case they contain an regex control characters.

---

If Regular expressions are new to you I found [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/) to be a good reference when I got started.

Comment: I agree with the regex approach but you are missing the LHS argument to the -notmatch operator.

Comment: @KeithHill I just assumed it was v4 syntax. Will update thanks. I realize how I made that silly mistake.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed. Thank you!